# How to absolute position a set of elements?

Tags: html, css

I set up 4 bocks in perfect allignment using absolute positioning.  My understanding is that this is that you basically setup the x,y location of each block using top, left and the parent element is the origin.  All worked as I expected and I marvelled at how nice things worked.  Than I hit the zoom button in IE 9 and although the y coordinates maintained there state...the x cooridanates shifted to the left..some even past the parent element..which makes even less sense b.c. I did not specify any negative values.  Why would zooming effect the absolute positioning?

Comment: It's not just zooming that is causing problems. Resizing the browser window has some interesting results as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this right...but what I ended up doing and what makes most since to me is to set up an x-y coordinate plane and position your elements using margins or top and left attributes.  To do this I set the parent div to relative positioning to make it register as the "origin" and then set my four square divs as absolute positioned.  This works well.  What through me off is that you have to set the parent div of you your absolution positioned elements to a non-static positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Zooming changes the size of these elements but not it's position. But I don't know how to prevent that, I think you cannot do anything against that because it's caused by the browser.

The only possibility is maybe checking the size with JavaScript, maybe it's possible to recognize this with JS, but that would be very difficult. Anyway, is it important that it works while zooming?

Answer (score 1):

Your absolute positioned elements are currently positioned relative to the `<body>` tag's top/left position (which is always 0px/0px).

But you have a centre aligned layout, with `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` and you want the absolutely positioned elements to line up with that perfectly.

Say you use zoom to make the page smaller by 50%. This will reduce the `left` position property by 50% and reduce the `width` of the `margin:auto;` element by 50% (triggering the left/right margins to be *increased* by whatever the width change is!).

So, zooming the page smaller makes the margin on the centred element *bigger* but it makes the absolute position coordinates *smaller*.

To make it line up perfectly, you need to make the absolute positioned elements relative to the element with `margin-left: auto;`.

In your specific example I would do this:

```
div#Ab1
{
  position: relative;
}

div#Ab1_2
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 0px; /* note: setting a right position, not a left position */
}

/* and do the same for div#Ab1_4 and div#Ab1_4_under */
```

Does that make sense?

PS: the reason it worked locally and then was broken when you uploaded, is you probably weren't viewing the page at the default zoom level on one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If your 4 blocks are identical in height and width, you could do this:

```
div.block { height: 200px; width: 400px; float: left; }
```

Then put them into a container that only allows two blocks side by side.

**Example Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/u5xVa/

Answer (score -1):

Don't avoid tables if they are they right way to go - aligning 4 blocks left to right, top to bottom, is easiest done with a table, imho. You can use div with float left and right and junk like that, but the cells in a table never shift out of alignment.

Comment: I agree with you in principle, but in this case I don't think a table is necessary. Also, I've had much better luck with `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;`